# Additional fields in schema.xml are not showing up when I do a query

Tags: solr, drupal-6, solr6

Solr version information: 6.6.0

The core is named: solr
Instance: /var/solr/data/new_core

In the  /var/solr/data/new_core/conf/ directory I have a custom schema.xml file

I have multiple custom fields like this in the schema.xml file

```
<field name="nid"  type="int" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

When I select the 'solr' core and go to query, these custom fields are not showing up in the results. Here's an example of the results:

```
{
  "response":{"numFound":200,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "id":"koe1eh/node/49",
        "site":"https://example.com:1881/",
        "hash":"koe1eh",
        "ss_language":"und",
        "url":"https://example.com:1881/node/49",
        "ss_name":"tfadmin",
        "tos_name":"tfadmin",
        "ss_name_formatted":"tfadmin",
        "tos_name_formatted":"tfadmin",
        "is_uid":1,
        "bs_status":true,
        "bs_sticky":false,
        "bs_promote":false,
        "is_tnid":0,
        "bs_translate":false,
        "ds_created":"2009-03-12T17:46:06Z",
        "ds_changed":"2009-06-18T15:25:33Z",
        "ds_last_comment_or_change":"2009-06-18T15:25:33Z",
        "tos_content_extra":" (Gifts) ",
        "sm_field_apptype":["mousepad"],
        "_version_":1588589404094464000,
        "timestamp":"2018-01-03T16:28:34Z"}]
  }}
```

The query performed is: `http://example.com/solr/solr/select?indent=on&q=*:*&rows=1&wt=json`

solrconfig.xml is here: https://pastebin.com/iVhZCqTW

schema.xml is here: https://pastebin.com/UBaUN5EK

I have tried restarting solr, reloading the core, and reindexing with no effect.

Comment: did you reindex?

Comment: Yes, as I said at the bottom, I have tried that

Comment: and you are positive you are indexing docs which have values for those fields you are missing?

Comment: Yes, one such field is nid, which is required for all nodes in Drupal. In the example above it has the nid value at the end up the url field:  `"url":"https://example.com:1881/node/49",`

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I was just looking at some entries that did not have those fields. When I altered my query to start on record 900, then I saw the fields I was looking for. I'm not sure what else I may have done to get this working as I've been trying many different things.